# json object in JSP

Tags: json, jsp, json-lib

I imported **net.sf.json** package to use the feature of **JSON** in my **jsp apge** but as soon as I create an object of JSONArray it throws me **NoClassDefinitionFound**.

```
//line 50
JSONObject responcedata=new JSONObject();


exception thrown is:
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: An exception occurred processing JSP page /jqgriddata.jsp at line 50


48: 
49: 
50:         JSONObject responcedata=new JSONObject();
51:         JSONArray cellarray=new JSONArray();
52: 
53:   //      responcedata.put("total",totalrow);


Stacktrace:
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.handleJspException(JspServletWrapper.java:510)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:401)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:313)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:260)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
root cause

javax.servlet.ServletException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class net.sf.json.JSONObject
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.doHandlePageException(PageContextImpl.java:862)
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.handlePageException(PageContextImpl.java:791)
    org.apache.jsp.jqgriddata_jsp._jspService(jqgriddata_jsp.java:191)
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:377)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:313)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:260)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
root cause

java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class net.sf.json.JSONObject
    org.apache.jsp.jqgriddata_jsp._jspService(jqgriddata_jsp.java:100)
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:377)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:313)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:
```

260)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's just telling that the mentioned class is missing in the webapp's runtime classpath. You need to [download](http://json-lib.sourceforge.net/) and drop the JAR file holding the classes of `net.sf.json` package in `/WEB-INF/lib` folder (don't forget to do the same for its dependencies as well, if necessary).

---

**Unrelated** to the concrete problem: writing Java code in a JSP file is a poor practice. Reading Roseindia.net tutorials is also a very bad idea as they only shows bad practices.